# Orientation and Paper on Print Setup dialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Working to a WPF Application (.NET fw 4.5), I can't find a way to display a print setup dialog as in the following image (I think it's based on Windows Forms but a WPF solution it would be better):
[image]

Using the code:

```
PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog(); 
myPrintDialog.ShowDialog();
```

I obtain a dialog with Print Range and Copies Settings (which I don't need) but not Paper and Orientation (which I want to get).

Comment: WPF has its own (?) method (actually, it doesn't) to show a Print Dialog, `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.ShowDialog()`. The page orientation could be accessed through the `Preferences` Button -- If you use this dialog, you have to add a Manifest to the Project and un-comment the dependency on `"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"` (usually at the bottom), otherwise the dialog is shown without visual styles. -- See also `CurrentPageEnabled`, `UserPageRangeEnabled`, `SelectedPagesEnabled` etc.

Comment: As a note, quite often both WPF and WinForms apps build their own interface to acquire user preferences and setup the Printer. The default Dialog is provided by the Driver, so you may want to use a single interface instead of a *semi-random* one (and expose the parts you want / can handle).

Comment: @Jimi, thank you very much for your hints. I know that it's possible to set orientation and paper size through Preferences button but I was tring to find a way to show them in the "first" dialog. I think that the Print Setup dialog that I posted is not a specific app implementation but a OS generic dialog, indeed I could find the same dialog in many apps and if I change the system language the dialog changes as well.